# running two separate Python-Flask api via a single docker file

Tags: python, docker

I want to run two different python api files running on different ports via a single container.

My docker file looks like:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-dev cmake libpoppler-cpp-dev poppler-utils tesseract-ocr

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt 



COPY . .

RUN chmod a+x run.sh

CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

And the .sh file looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec python3 /app1/numberToWord.py &
exec python3 /app2/dollarToGbp.py &
```

While the docker build is a success without any error, the docker run doesn't throw any error and exits the command line. I'm curios to know where is it failing, any insight is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)** to ignore hangup signal

**Ex:**

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup python3 /app1/numberToWord.py &
nohup python3 /app2/dollarToGbp.py &
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run a container, you can specify the specific command to run.  You can run two containers, from the same image, with different commands:

```sh
docker run -p 8000:8000 --name spelling -d image /app1/numberToWord.py
docker run -p 8001:8000 --name currency -d image /app2/dollarToGbp.py
```

The important points here are that each container runs a *single* process, in the *foreground*.

If your main command script makes it to the end and exits, the container will exit too.  The script you show only launches background processes and then completes, and when it completes the container will exit.  There needs to be some foreground process to keep the container running, and the easiest way to do this is to just launch the main server you need to run as the only process in the container.